# import folder of .txt files into word document

Tags: vba, automation, ms-word

I've found a lot on importing folder of .txt files into excel, but not many on importing .txt files into word. I'm trying to get my macro to open all .txt files in a specific folder and import them into a single word document, with each .txt file having its own page. This is the code I have so far (that I found online):

```
Sub AllFilesInFolder()
    Dim myFolder As String, myFile As String
    myFolder = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Show
        If .SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
            myFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
        End If
    End With
    myFile = Dir(myFolder & "\*.txt") '
    Do While myFile <> ""
        Open myFolder & "\" & myFile For Input As #1
        'Copy & Paste Macro?
        myFile = Dir
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Good job on finding the code. Now tell us what problems are you facing with the code and what did you try changing in it to make it work :)

Comment: Word has an Insert ► Text ► Object ► Text from File command that is better suited to inserting text from a file. If you record yourself bringing in one or two TXT files, the rest should be pretty evident. Come back if you are having trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is something to get you started

<kbd>**Word 2010**</kbd>

**Edit**  this should allow you to open all txt files in one document and save it

```
Option Explicit
Sub AllFilesInFolder()
    Dim myFolder    As String
    Dim myFile      As String
    Dim wdDoc       As Document
    Dim txtFiles    As Document

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    myFolder = openFolder

    If myFolder = "" Then Exit Sub

    myFile = Dir(myFolder & "\*.txt", vbNormal)
    Set wdDoc = ActiveDocument

    While myFile <> ""
        Set txtFiles = Documents.Open(FileName:=myFolder & "\" & myFile, AddToRecentFiles:=False, Visible:=False, ConfirmConversions:=False)
        wdDoc.Range.InsertAfter txtFiles.Range.Text & vbCr
        txtFiles.Close SaveChanges:=True
    myFile = Dir()
    Wend

    Set txtFiles = Nothing
    Set wdDoc = Nothing

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub     
Function openFolder() As String

    Dim oFolder     As Object

    openFolder = ""

    Set oFolder = CreateObject("Shell.Application").BrowseForFolder(0, "Choose a folder", 0)
        If (Not oFolder Is Nothing) Then openFolder = oFolder.Items.Item.Path

    Set oFolder = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you! This code opens each text file as an individual word document, but I'm wondering how to get it into a single document. I added objDoc.SaveAs ("P:\ImportedDescriptions.doc") as an attempt to save the documents, but it only saved the last one. Should my code save each new document and then merge it into one, or is it possible to directly import the text files into one document? Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: Would it involve creating an array?

Answer (score 1):

Copy all the text files into a single file using the Command Prompt (cmd.exe) and the following command:

```
copy *.txt NewFile.txt
```

Then open this file with word and modify the way you want to see the text.