# How to Format Text Style to "Heading 1" while importing all Txt files into Word document

Tags: vba, ms-word, format, styles

I used this method to import all files into Word document.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30494740/908080

I added to include File Name before the content text like this

```
With wdDoc.Range
     .InsertAfter FileCnt & ". "
     .InsertAfter myFile & vbCr
     .InsertParagraphAfter
     .InsertAfter txtFiles.Range.Text & vbCr
End With
```

It works fine. 
Is it possible to Set the Format for FileName Text to be "Heading 1" and rest content as Normal Text. 
Once done, I can create a TOC and go to the required file quickly.

So it need to look like

**1. File1.Txt**

This is File1 Text

**2. File2.Txt**

This is File2 Text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible, but doing it (easily) requires a slightly different approach for handling the target `Range`. Something more like this (untested):

```
Dim rng as Word.Range
Set rng = wdDoc.Content 'a property that returns a Range; Doc.Range is a method
rng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
With rng
     .Text = FileCnt & ". " &  myFile & vbCr
     .Style = wdStyleHeading1
     .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
     .Text = vbCr & txtFiles.Range.Text & vbCr
     .Style = wdStyleNormal
End With
```

Think of working with a dedicated `Range` object like working with a Selection - "collapsing" is like pressing an arrow key. So enter content, format, then go to the end (or the start). Then repeat for the next content.